# Extract information from the string and convert to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string like below:

```
[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.5324998, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=250.44,Y=223.48499) height=3.5324998 width=4.2910004]DECEMBER 31,

[Base Font : IOFOEO+Imago-Book, Font Size : 3.876, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=307.5,Y=240.48499) height=3.876 width=2.9970093]respectively. The net decrease in the revenue

[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.5324998, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=49.5,Y=233.98499) height=3.5324998 width=2.5690002](US$ in millions)
```

I want to extract the value of "X" and the text associated and convert it to a list. Please, see the expected output below:

**Expected Output:**

```
['X=250.44','DECEMBER 31,']
['X=307.5','respectively. The net decrease in the revenue']
['X=49.5','(US$ in millions)']
```

How can we approach this in Python?

**MyApproach:**

```
mylist = []
for line in data.split("\n"):
    if line.strip():
        x_coord = re.findall('^(X=.*)\,$', line)
        text = re.findall('^(]\w +)', line)
        mylist.append([x_coord, text])
```

My approach does not identify any value for `x_coord` and `text`.

Comment: Have a look at the [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function or Python's [regex library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: I would go the `re` way

Comment: str.split() may not work but definitely regex has to be used. I am not able to extract the information using regex and convert to list so I approached SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re` solution:

```py
import re

input = [
    "[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.5324998, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=250.44,Y=223.48499) height=3.5324998 width=4.2910004]DECEMBER 31,",
    "[Base Font : IOFOEO+Imago-Book, Font Size : 3.876, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=307.5,Y=240.48499) height=3.876 width=2.9970093]respectively. The net decrease in the revenue",
    "[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.5324998, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=49.5,Y=233.98499) height=3.5324998 width=2.5690002](US$ in millions)",
]

def extract(s):
    match = re.search("(X=\d+(?:\.\d*)?).*?\](.*?)$",s)
    return match.groups()

output = [extract(item) for item in input]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[
    ('X=250.44', 'DECEMBER 31,'),
    ('X=307.5', 'respectively. The net decrease in the revenue'),
    ('X=49.5', '(US$ in millions)'),
]
```

Explanation:

- `\d` ... digit
- `\d+` ... one or more digits
- `(?:...)` ... non-capturing ("normal") parentheses
- `\.\d*` ... dot followed by zero or more digits
- `(?:\.\d*)?` ... optional (zero or one) "decimal part"
- `(X=\d+(?:\.\d*)?)` ... first group, `X=number`
- `.*?` ... zero or more of any character (non-greedy)
- `\]` ... `]` symbol
- `$` ... end of string
- `\](.*?)$` ... second group, anything between `]` and end of string

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(X=[^,]*)(?:.*])(.*)
```

```py
import re

source = """[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.5324998, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=250.44,Y=223.48499) height=3.5324998 width=4.2910004]DECEMBER 31,
[Base Font : IOFOEO+Imago-Book, Font Size : 3.876, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=307.5,Y=240.48499) height=3.876 width=2.9970093]respectively. The net decrease in the revenue
[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.5324998, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=49.5,Y=233.98499) height=3.5324998 width=2.5690002](US$ in millions)""".split('\n')

pattern = r"(X=[^,]*)(?:.*])(.*)"

for line in source:
    print(re.search(pattern, line).groups())
```

Output:

```
('X=250.44', 'DECEMBER 31,')
('X=307.5', 'respectively. The net decrease in the revenue')
('X=49.5', '(US$ in millions)')
```

You have `X=` in front of all captures, so I just did a capture group, feel free to add non-capturing group if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex with named groups to capture the relevant bits:

```
>>> line = "[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.5324998, Font Weight : 0.0] [(X=250.44,Y=223.48499) height=3.5324998 width=4.2910004]DECEMBER 31,"
>>> m = re.search(r'(?:\(X=)(?P<x_coord>.*?)(?:,.*])(?P<text>.*)$', line)
>>> m.groups()
('250.44', 'DECEMBER 31,')
>>> m['x_coord']
'250.44'
>>> m['text']
'DECEMBER 31,'
```